# Why does my GKE cluster not show any events?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I have a GKE cluster and deployed some workloads on it. What I noticed is that whenever I do `kubectl get events --all-namespaces`, I don't see any results. `kubectl describe deployment <name>` doesn't show any events either. I'm pretty sure things do happen in my cluster because all my workloads are running fine and Stackdriver is able to report logs and HPA functions perfectly. But my events section is empty all over. Why is this? Is this something I've to enable manually in GKE?

Comment: Hi there. What GKE version are you running? Is this something that began to happen or this was always the behavior?

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas I'm using v1.16.9-gke.6. I do not know if this was always the case, since this is a very new cluster I've spun up. I'm used to using Kubernetes in bare metal and in Azure and I've always found a lot of events in both instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kubernetes events are retained by default a period of 1 hour which is controlled by kube-apiserver. You would not have performed any activity in an hour.

check event-ttl [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) , code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da53a247633/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/options/options.go#L71-L72)

Also you can check this merge request for latest enhancements in kubectl events [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1440)

Comment: Everyday I learn something new! Thanks for the pointers. This was it. I forced some operations and the events show up.