# Pod with no events

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to find event related to my pod `kuebctl describe pod <pod_name>` but I am seeing blank events.

```
Events:          <none>
```

I have the application deployed in AWS EKS. I think this has started to happen when one of my nodes got replaced with another one. How do i ensure that i see the events.

when I see the output of `kubectl get pods` I see restart count = 1 for one of my pods which indicate there should be some events.

Any help on how to investigate this further would be really great, thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: If you deploy a new pod, does can you see its events?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63038740/4518472

Comment: You can also check if with `kubectl get events` you have any event related to those Pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to have no events on the pods if no event was generated in the last 60 minutes. I have same behavior in my cluster as well:

```
kubectl describe pod prometheus-77566c9987-95g92 -n istio-system | grep -i events
Events:          <none>
```

The default events-ttl(time to live) is 60 minutes.

Actually, while trying to decrease my ttl to reproduce an see if the events disappear without having to wait, I went into this [SR](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/785) , that's asking for this value to be configurable via the AWS web portal.

For longer lived and advanced logging, you need to persist the events/logs or leverage the built-in logging systems offered by your cloud provider. If you want to do it yourself, there are plenty of options for doing this(Stackdriver,Prometheues,ELK).

However, if you want to increase the [ttl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) of the events, you must change the config through the api-server as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356764/13736525).

Answer (score 1):

The events are only available for around 1 hr. If you perform some operation on pod then you will see events for next 1 hr.